# Tools for generating constraints for linear programs

Tags: soft-question, linear-programming

Are there any freely available tools that aid in generating LP formulations in a way that can be fed into some solver?

Say I have a few hundred variables, all which have to satisfy the same constraints, then it would be tedious to manually generate these; or, if the sum of the absolute values of the variable is subject to some constraint, then that also is easier said than written out explicitly.

So are there any tools that are capable of generating (textual) LP formulations from a more abstract description using quantifiers, loops or ranges, that can be fed into solvers?

Comment: Im Prinzip ist hier [Lingo](https://www.lindo.com/index.php/ls-downloads/try-lingo) hilfreich. Bei der trial version kann man bis 300 Variablen verwenden. // In principle  [Lingo](https://www.lindo.com/index.php/ls-downloads/try-lingo) is helpful. In the trial version one can use 300 variables.

Comment: Some free tools are GLPK, YALMIP, PuLP and Cylp.

Comment: @callculus I added a translation. Please try to stick to English as much as possible.

Comment: @quid Thanks for the translation. I appreciate that you was able to translate it. Usually I write my comments in English. This was an exemption.

Comment: @callculus you are welcome. It's not a big deal. We even allow users to resort to other languages, besides English, if there are problems of understanding. Only as a general principle it's better to stick to English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org/) is dedicated to rule-based generation of $LP$ programs while also abstracting specific format-requirements of various solvers